# Do all browsers allow me to replace color # with rgba?

Tags: css

The application I am working on is using the following CSS:

```
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

I have used color numbers but is it possible to use rgba for all of these browsers or does some not accept rgba?

Answer (score 1):

rgba is supported for all of these browsers the newer versions

here you can find more about the support of browsers http://css-tricks.com/examples/RGBaSupport/

Answer (score 0):

Check [this out](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)!..... Im sure it will help you!

Comment: I know it's frowned to just post links, but that link **is** great to find older browser compatability. **EDIT**, but sorry, @IvoJonkers link is better :)

Comment: Right, but very great information that pertains to this :) @ iight its the same site lol...

Answer (score 0):

I have personally tested CSS3 colors to work in Chrome 23, Firefox 17, and IE9. I also use [this site](http://caniuse.com) to check browser support for CSS3 features as well as HTML5.